# How can i locate my login at center of the page, if my HTML body does not take whole space. Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

The red zone is the login Component and I want put my login at the center of whole page view, but i don´t know why my html and body tag don´t take all the whole blank space.
Anyway if you wanna take a look to my project, then i leave my github project https://github.com/SIGX-SENPAI/Angular-VRChat

LoginComponent.html

```
<form class="dropdown p-5 justify-content-center bg-danger">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail2" placeholder="email@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck2">
        Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

AppComponent.html

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="login" (showNav)="login = $event" (showOut)="local = $event"></app-navbar>

<div class="container" *ngIf="!local">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="local">

  <!-- <iframe width="100%" height="450px"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PWLPw4RE9Ig?controls=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&mute=1" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe> -->

  <div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <app-promo></app-promo>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <app-home></app-home>
  </div>
  <app-features></app-features>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi3T6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A0Sk.png)

The html body  is the blue shadow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fun9B.png)

Comment: please create stackblitz link

Comment: your body only takes as much space as needed to fit child elements but I believe you can force it with body { height: 100vh; }

Comment: i got the solution, but i will make a stackblitz link anyway for any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the body 100%, you also need to make the html 100%?

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: should  I put at the style.css file? Because it just works when they are in a another tag with size defined.

Comment: It should go at the beginning of the css file that is trying to centre your login. If that is style.css then yes.

Comment: yeah it works too, thanks, i forgot these can be resized at the user screen.

Answer (score 0):

- I see you are using bootstrapp.css
- You dont need justify-content-center unless you are not making the element display flex `d-flex`

Try one of these:

Here you wrap the button in another form-group and center the button inside that wrapper

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="dropdown p-5 bg-danger">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail2" placeholder="email@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck2">
        Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-auto d-inline-block">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here you can tell form element to center all texts, but then for all form-groups to left aling the labels

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="dropdown text-center p-5 bg-danger">
  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail2" placeholder="email@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck2">
        Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-auto d-inline-block">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You got reason, it was not necessary the justify. The second code works more less well, i needed to complete with other help i got, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use the padding-top attribute then just find a procentage that makes it move to the middle of the screen.

```
Body /*Or whatever class or id you wanna move*/ {
padding-top: 20%; 
}
```

That is the way i get around. It isn't the most professional way to do it i think but it workes

Comment: It works as you said, needed to put at a class in the loginComponent, maybe not the professional way but it is better for now  i think.